# Make a div background color on top of other elements

Tags: html, css

I currently have a set of elements like the following :

```
<ul class="stats clearfix">
    <li class="first">
       <span>93%</span>
    </li>
    <li>
       <span>
         <strong>€ 5.500</strong>Goal
       </span>
    </li>
    <li class="last">
       <span>
         <strong class="no-end-date">-</strong>
       </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Each of the li elements has a background color, however I want to make a div on the top of them having its own background color that should cover the other background colors of the other li elements.
I already tried wrapping the ul element with a div and setting all elements position to relative and having a z-index of 100 for my div, however the background color seems to be behind the ul element and not on the top of it.
Any suggestions?
Here's the html and css I tried

```
<div id="myoverlay" style="
   position: relative;
   z-index: 100;
   background-color: black;
   ">
   <ul class="stats clearfix" style="
      position: relative;
      ">
      <li class="first">
         <span>93%</span>
      </li>
      <li>
         <span>
         <strong>€ 5.500</strong>
         Goal</span>
      </li>
      <li class="last">
         <span>
         <strong class="no-end-date">-</strong>
         </span>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Include the html defining the overlay div and the css you are using - otherwise any bug hunt will be wild guessing. However, your description will not work as the overlay div is an ancestor of the elements to be covered - they'll inherit the z-index property. either expressly set their z-index or detach your div from the ancestor chain of the ul.

Comment: @collapsar thanks for your reply, I have include the html and css for my solution in the post.

Comment: On a second thought, your complex may be more complex. You seem to try to slip a styling layer between your list elements' foreground and background. I think this can only be simulated in css alone by re-setting the li's background color with a selector involving the div ancestor, eg. `div#myoverlay, div#myoverlay  li { background-color: red; }`. this selector should have a higher  specificity than the selectors through which the li backgrounds are set

Answer (score 1):

You could place an absolutely positioned `div` element next to the list and wrap them both inside of a container with `position: relative`.

```css
li {
  background-color: red;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
  z-index: 100;
  
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="overlay"></div>
   <ul class="stats clearfix">
      <li class="first">
         <span>93%</span>
      </li>
      <li>
         <span>
         <strong>€ 5.500</strong>
         Goal</span>
      </li>
      <li class="last">
         <span>
         <strong class="no-end-date">-</strong>
         </span>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```